# Angularfire: How to push an object into another object in a $firebaseArray?

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

I have this object in firebase:

```
Groups
    -id1
    name: a

    -id2
    name: b

    -id3
    name: c
```

I use "Groups" this way:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com/Groups");
$scope.groups = $firebaseArray(ref)

$scope.groups.$add({
    "name": "d"
    }).then(function (ref)
    {
        console.log('Added group');
    }, function (error)
    {
        console.error("Error:", error);
    });
```

Some of these groups contain items. How do I add an array and push some items in it? How to handle the case where the array already exists?

This doesn't work:

```
var group = Groups.$getRecord(id3)
if(!group.hasOwnProperty('items')){
    group['items'] = []
}
group['items'].push({item: "an item"})
```

Comment: What is `Groups.$getRecord(id3)`? Same for `group.$push()`, because afaik AngularFire does not have a `$push()` method.

Comment: I use getRecord to get the object that contains the group data. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, [avoid nested arrays](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html#section-angularfire-intro) and [flatten data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-flatten) where possible.

If these items are updated asynchronously by multiple users, you will have conflicts and strange behaviors, because [arrays in distributed data](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) kill baby kittens.

Create your array directly on the items to be added and use push ids instead:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com/Groups/d/items");
$scope.items = $firebaseArray(ref)
$scope.items.$add({ $value: "an item" });
```

Or, if we're going to synchronize on `groups` and really want to sync every change to every group every time, then this would be simpler and better:

```
new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com/Groups/d/items").push("an item");
```

Comment: Thanks @Kato! I'm building an app that will be used on a single device, that is why I don't give a damn about concurrent operations. :)